# Python multiprocessing queue fails with subprocesses

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to add spawned subprocesses to a queue so that only one can execute at a time. I don't want to wait for the process to execute with each iteration of the for loop because there is some code at the beginning of the loop that can run in parallel with the processes.

Example code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
import subprocess

q = Queue()

hrs = range(0,12)

for hr in hrs:
    print(hr)
    # There will be other code here that takes some time to run
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py', '--hr={}'.format(hr)])
    q.put(p)
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kschneider/anaconda3/envs/ewall/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 239, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/kschneider/anaconda3/envs/ewall/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Is there a different way to set this up that will not result in the thread lock errors?

Comment: You may want to take advantage of a `multiprocessing.Pool` instead. If your goal is to have them run one at a time, simply specify `workers=1` when initializing the pool. Then you don't have to worry about manually synchronizing with a queue.

Comment: This approach will not work anyway.  The call to Popen "executes a child program in a new process."  Adding it to Queue will not have the effect of running the processes one at a time, since by the time you add them into the Queue they are already running.  The only way I can see to do what you want is for each process to signal the parent that it has finished.  There are methods for doing that sort of thing in the subprocess module.

Comment: Thanks @PaulCornelius, that should've been more obvious to me. There is a wait() method of the subprocess class that does exactly what I want!